# Execute pipeline/run of Kubeflow from command line

Tags: kubernetes, kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines

I'm executing some experiments on a Kubeflow cluster and I was wondering if there is a faster way than using the Kubeflow UI to set up the run input parameters.
I would like to connect from command line to the Kubefow cluster and run executions from there but i cannot find any documentation.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Kubeflow pipelines has a command line tool called [kfp](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/components/pipelines/sdk/sdk-overview/#kubeflow-pipelines-cli-tool), so for example you can use `kfp run submit` to start a run.